# Redundant method within TimeSpan

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, timespan

When I use `TimeSpan` class there is a [`Add()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,574ccdd4f806977f,references) extension method

```
public TimeSpan Add(TimeSpan ts) {
  long result = _ticks + ts._ticks;
  // Overflow if signs of operands was identical and result's
  // sign was opposite.
  // >> 63 gives the sign bit (either 64 1's or 64 0's).
  if ((_ticks >> 63 == ts._ticks >> 63) && (_ticks >> 63 != result >> 63))
       throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_TimeSpanTooLong"));
   return new TimeSpan(result);
}
```

Basically it does the same as the `+` operator.

```
public static TimeSpan operator +(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2) {
    return t1.Add(t2);
}
```

Add values and throw a exception in case of a overflow.

**Question:**

Why does `.NET` provide this method?  wouldn't be

```
public static TimeSpan operator +(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2)
```

enough? e.g. `int` also doesn't provide a `Add` method.

Comment: Why does `ArgumentException` take its parameters in a different order to `ArgumentNullException`? Aren't there more important things to wonder about?

Comment: That would make sense if I were trying to refute what you were saying or discredit you in some way, but I am not. I'm merely saying that I don't understand the point of debating minor design decisions like this, when evidenced by the two examples I provided, .NET is clearly worked on by many different people, and probably many distinct teams, who develop different parts at different times.

Comment: I imagine that the team that developed `TimeSpan` had the philosophy that there should be methods to do this.

Comment: (Speculations, with assumption that operator overloads came later) I imagine it had something to do with `TimeSpan` being an `Object` and not a primite type and as such it started out with a `method`. Later on (couldn't find when they were introduced) operator overloads came enabling this syntax and `Add(..)` was kept for backwards compatibility.

Comment: `extension method` It is a method, not an _extension_ method. As to why it is there? Well, it is hard to be sure but likely for two main reasons. a) Consistency (e.g. `DateTime` has `Add`) b) Discoverability (I have used C# for *many* years and never have used the + operator with it (since I didn't know it was there), but I have used `Add`). And considering there is no real **downside** of their decision, it seems to have been a smart call.